# Spring integration DSL lastTime not updating on error

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I'm totally new at Spring integration DSL stuff, what I'm trying to do is fetch all the RSS feeds from mongo, register them all into the flow context and have that process all the articles fetched from the feeds. Currently I have a for-each loop that calls a function containing the following:

```
IntegrationFlow newFlow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(Feed.inboundAdapter(new URL(url), source), e -> e.id(org + "-" + source + "-feed").poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(poll).maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessages).errorChannel("feedErrors")))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("sourceId", sourceId))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("sourceName", sourceName))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", source))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("categories", categories))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("org", org))
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(taskExecutor))
            .handle("enricher", "enhance")
            .channel(news())
            .get();
        
this.flowContext.registration(newFlow).id(org + "-" + source + "-flow").register();
```

It does so splendidly with the exception of exceptions, funnily enough. When a feed is currently unavailable, has been renamed or the article from the feed itself is malformed an exception is thrown and it goes to the "feedErrors" channel as indicated in the flow definition. That part looks as following:

```
@Component
public class RssFeedErrorHandler {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RssFeedErrorHandler.class);

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorSender() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("feedErrors")
            .handle("rssFeedErrorHandler", "handleError")
            .get();
    }

    public void handleError(Message<MessagingException> message) {
        logger.error(message.toString());
    }
}
```

Exception examples:

```
AdviceMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://news.google.com/rss/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRFZ4ZERBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen, feedResource=null, metadataKey='google-news-politics.https://news.google.com/rss/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRFZ4ZERBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen', lastTime=1613665200000}'; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://news.google.com/rss/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRFZ4ZERBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen was successful, headers={id=101f3da9-42de-eb03-0da2-015952fc0a23, timestamp=1613667428995}, inputMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://news.google.com/rss/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRFZ4ZERBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen, feedResource=null, metadataKey='google-news-politics.https://news.google.com/rss/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRFZ4ZERBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen', lastTime=1613665200000}'; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://news.google.com/rss/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNRFZ4ZERBU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen, headers={id=8a470a5f-4027-371c-44fd-1250703077b0, timestamp=1613667428995}]]
AdviceMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://www.startupbootcamp.org/feed/, feedResource=null, metadataKey='startupbootcamp-startups.https://www.startupbootcamp.org/feed/', lastTime=1613015630000}'; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) was successful, headers={id=6b5a1a00-905a-68b6-128b-4cdd8eb06737, timestamp=1613664837150}, inputMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://www.startupbootcamp.org/feed/, feedResource=null, metadataKey='startupbootcamp-startups.https://www.startupbootcamp.org/feed/', lastTime=1613015630000}'; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out), headers={id=70ef8ae7-1b75-9e38-e631-c88777741609, timestamp=1613664837150}]]
AdviceMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms, feedResource=null, metadataKey='india-times-entertainment.https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms', lastTime=1613715922000}'; nested exception is com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character. was successful, headers={id=fb936878-6450-d79a-851a-ca1ceeef8182, timestamp=1613705658735}, inputMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms, feedResource=null, metadataKey='india-times-entertainment.https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms', lastTime=1613715922000}'; nested exception is com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character., headers={id=24f2a11a-80a6-6c13-dbe1-9548747174aa, timestamp=1613705658734}]]
AdviceMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://www.jeffbullas.com/feed/, feedResource=null, metadataKey='jeff-bullas-marketing.https://www.jeffbullas.com/feed/', lastTime=1613574000000}'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.jeffbullas.com/feed/ was successful, headers={id=e6998e35-afdc-b476-c2d9-2f4b0cc46c6b, timestamp=1613710313323}, inputMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://www.jeffbullas.com/feed/, feedResource=null, metadataKey='jeff-bullas-marketing.https://www.jeffbullas.com/feed/', lastTime=1613574000000}'; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.jeffbullas.com/feed/, headers={id=420f9b5d-1c58-cd0a-c4e2-5d640578f1c9, timestamp=1613710313322}]]
```

Here's two full stacks:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms, feedResource=null, metadataKey='india-times-entertainment.https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms', lastTime=-1}'; nested exception is com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:239)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.populateEntryList(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:202)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:177)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:58)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:359)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.
        at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:236)
        at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:150)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:226)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:232)
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:303)
        at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1196)
        at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:233)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 15681; Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanCharReferenceValue(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanCharReference(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
        ... 25 more


org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/rss, feedResource=null, metadataKey='independent-politics.http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/rss', lastTime=1613726122000}'; nested exception is com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:239)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.populateEntryList(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:202)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:177)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:58)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:359)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:236)
        at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:150)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:226)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:232)
            at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:303)
        at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1196)
        at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:233)
            ... 22 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
        ... 25 more
```

So the error is thrown, it's logged and life goes on, except for some reason that poll fetch seems to be saved for a retry. This wouldn't be an issue if it retried it once, but it just keeps retrying over and over, and when enough of errors pile up it just keeps retrying those errors and nothing new is ever fetched.

For example, 500 feeds are polled, 10 of those throw an exception where the feed has been either moved so it no longer exists, it has bad xml or something else might have happened. Now the poller is stuck polling those 10 feeds over and over again until it no longer fails (which never happens). I remember reading somewhere that if exception is thrown in `handleError` function then it would keep retrying, but if no exception is thrown there it should move on. That doesn't seem to be the case here. I've spend 3 days now mulling over this, trying different solutions but It always just chokes up after about 4-10 minutes, depending on how long it takes to fetch enough feeds with errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you try to talk about many different exceptions: not available, malformed, processing error etc. I think the best practice is to distinguish those exceptions and made an appropriate business decision for each of them: we definitely can't treat "not available" as processing error and must retry until it is available back.

For the processing one I would suggest to look into a `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on the service where your process entries of the feed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

For malformed source I'd suggest to take a look into a flow removal form the context. So, you won't try to poll a wrong source any more. You definitely can do that from the error flow on that `feedErrors` channel.

And so on for other errors you face with this scenario.

We probably may revise your `10 are of those throw an exception where the feeds have been removed for whatever reason` in more details since the logic in the `FeedEntryMessageSource` is based on the `updatedDate` of the entry. So, if we couldn't convert it properly and produce, it is really going to be pulled again next time since the `lastTime` state has not been updated appropriately. But let's do that in the separate SO thread with much more details to investigate!

**UPDATE**

Some thoughts regarding your stack traces.

The exception like `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 15681; Character refer` is not good and must be treated as fatal. You definitely can't parse that RSS source any more or at least until it comes back to normal. This kind of exception could be handled like a `stop()` for that `Feed.inboundAdapter()`. So, you catch an exception in the `feedErrors` channel flow and call the `stop()` of caused endpoint. Or even better just remove the whole dynamic flow for this RSS source.

The exception `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 10; DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.` is also not good and probably could be treated the same fatal way with subsequent `stop()` for the endpoint. Or you can investigate  the `xerces` library how to allow that DTD declaration. Probably the option like `syndFeedInput(SyndFeedInput)` could also give you some hooks for the XML parsing. For example I see it has this option:

```
/**
 * Since ROME 1.5.1 we fixed a security vulnerability by disallowing Doctype declarations by default. 
 * This change breaks the compatibility with at least RSS 0.91N because it requires a Doctype declaration. 
 * You are able to allow Doctype declarations again with this property. You should only activate it 
 * when the feeds that you process are absolutely trustful. 
 *  
 * @param allowDoctypes true when Doctype declarations should be allowed again, false otherwise
 */
public void setAllowDoctypes(boolean allowDoctypes) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice in setting up error handling for separate business cases, I'll definitively implement that at a later date, but currently my main concern is the metadata not updating. Is there any way to simply implement that through configuration? I have `metadataStore` bean defined, and it just does `return new MongoDbMetadataStore(factory, "integrationMetadataStore");`. I could probably parse the exception message for the `metadataKey` and then manually update the collection with current epoch time, but that just seems janky. I'd much rather prefer a proper config if that's possible.

Comment: Yeah... as I said: need more details on the matter . Doesn’t look like it is related to this question about general error handling

Comment: What would you need for example? I'm willing to provide, but the above is all I know that could be related to it. Logs are clean, a bunch of "New message from feed <XYZ> stored" and then it just stops. The app keeps running but nothing new is stored.

Comment: What I need is a stack trace for an error when it doesn't update metadata for the `lastTime` value. And I don't know what is that `New message from feed` message. Who says that into logs?

Comment: That's my logging currently for dev purposes. There are a few warnings for invalid cookie headers, but no errors/exceptions from spring integration/messaging besides my own logging. I'll try to provide better logs by setting spring logging level to debug.

Comment: My point is if it doesn't reach your logic, then `Feed.inboundAdapter()` has some errors parsing feed entries and those errors must go to your `feedErrors`. This is the part I'd like to see - the error when it doesn't update the metadata and doesn't let you to go for the next entry in the feed. When we know more, we can figure out if we need to do anything on the framework level to avoid the problem. If that is not a `Feed.inboundAdapter()` problem, then it is your custom logic and it really has to be handled on your side. But still would be great to see such a stack trace.

Comment: I've updated the question with stack traces, hopefully this reveals something.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I've implemented the changes, and it does get rid of the failing feeds, but it still chokes up. I set spring logging to trace and found that even some time after it chokes up it keeps polling and receiving messages, but that's it, they don't really go anywhere. Unfortunately, I've found nothing else of use, but I'll keep at it and update if I find anything noteworthy